# Why is Firefox filling my thead as the entire height of the table?

Tags: css, firefox, html-table

Here's a fiddle of the problem:

https://jsfiddle.net/gtfoeasy/8/

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <table style="min-height: 100px">
            <thead>
                <tr><td style="background: blue">Test</td></tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

In Firefox, the thead is filling the entire height of the table where in chrome it is not.

This seems to be a new issue that is causing me problems.

Any ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: Because current Chrome doesn't respect your min-height on the table. Chrome Canary does the same as Firefox.

Comment: Why *shouldn't* it fill the full height if you don't have anything else in your table, i.e. if that's the full content of the table?

Comment: @Johannes Why does it fill in Firefox, but NOT in Chrome?  I would expect a thead to not be 100% height.

Answer (score -1):

What I've been able to deduce so far is that Firefox made a change where tables now inherit the flex properties of the parent div where before it didn't.